# How to calculate distance from new coordinates in distancefile in GeoNear mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo Db and I need to calculate distance from different coordinate other than provided in Near. How can I do that `

```
BsonDocument geoNear1 = new BsonDocument {
                { "$geoNear", new BsonDocument {
                    { "near", new BsonDocument {
                        { "type", "Point" },
                        { "coordinates", new BsonArray { -82.7469202, 2.0479533} }
                    }},
                    { "spherical", true },
                    { "limit", 50},
                    { "maxDistance", 5000 },
                    { "distanceField", "distance" }
                }}
            };
```

`

Is there any way so that I can pass new coordinates in distancefield, and distance should be measured from those coordinates?